# Why doesnt my rectangle draw to the JFrame?

Tags: java

I'm trying to draw a rectangle in a window. The window is appearing, but not the rectangle, what am I doing wrong? Can someone just give me a simple explanation, thanks

```
  import java.awt.Graphics;

   import javax.swing.JFrame;

  public class Moving{
  public static void main (String[]args) {
  Main();
  drawShape(null);
 }
public static void Main () {
JFrame frame= new JFrame () ;
frame.setVisible(true);
 frame.setSize(400, 400);

}

public static void drawShape(Graphics g) {
g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
}
```

Comment: Please, read some [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) first.

Comment: Because you are passing null, to start with. But better read a tutorial first.

Comment: I have read the tutorials, can someone just give me an explanation please

Comment: _I have read the tutorials._ Then you might also know about `paint(-)`. If not read about it.

Comment: Should I pass something other than null

Comment: You don't think `drawShape(null);` is going to cause you a problem? Maybe you should have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 0):

First off, there isn't much point to having 2 main methods, so it would be best to combine them. Second, you need a Graphics object in order to draw and you're passing `null`. What do you think will happen with (null graphic).draw()? You need to pass the graphic your frame is using.

```
public static void main (String[]args) {
    JFrame frame= new JFrame ();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    Graphics g = frame.getGraphics();
    drawShape(g);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: `getGraphics` can return `null` and you should NEVER use it, this is not how painting is done in Swing

Comment: @MadProgrammer Heh.. Good to know the quality of that first Java class I took then lol